# Carregar múltiplos arquivos Amazon S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-aws

Estou tentando carregar múltiplos arquivos que estão no Amazon S3, estou usando Panda, Anaconda, porém estou com erro.

```
bg = s3.Bucket("bucket")
objects = bg.objects.filter(Prefix="bucket/")

for obj in s3.Bucket('bucket').objects.all():
    print (obj)

file_list = []
for obj in objects:
    df = pd.read_csv(f's3://bucket/{obj.key}')
    file_list.append(df)
    final_df = pd.concat(file_list)
```

Output:

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='codigo_python.txt')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='codigo_python_V2.txt')
```

Mensagem de erro

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Comment: O valor de objects não deveria ser `s3.Bucket('bucket').objects.all()` ??? Ou seja `objects = s3.Bucket('bucket').objects.all()` e depois `for object in objects`?

Comment: Alterei e agora o que retorna é EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
Desculpa mas eu estou tentando entender os códigos que veja nos forums, mas em nenhum eu consegui fazer essa leitura, mas fiz a alteração que você sugeriu

Answer (score 0):

A alteração abaixo deve funcionar.

```
bg = s3.Bucket("bucket")
objects = bg.objects.filter(Prefix="bucket/")
obj_summary = s3.Bucket('bucket').objects.all()

file_list = []
for obj in obj_summary:
    print (obj)
    file_object = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='{obj.key}')
    df = pd.read_csv(file_object['Body'])
    file_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(file_list)
```

Comment: Esta com o seguinte erro: EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
Já inclui header=None, delim_whitespace=True,index_col=0)
Quando a leitura é feita para um arquivo especifico não há erro algum, ao ler vários está com esse novo erro.

Comment: @user223488, em que linha do código vc recebe este erro?

Comment: No read_csv
df = pd.read_csv(f's3://bucket/{obj.key}',header=None, delim_whitespace=True,index_col=0)

Comment: @user223488, alterei o código no post apontando para o `file_object`. Veja qual o resultado disso.